# Javascript not working in sending data

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, jquery

This is the script which will send information of textboxes to another page where the information will be inserted into the mysql database.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        // click to submit an event
        $('#Create').click(function(){

            var a = $("#EventInput").val();

            if(a != "What are you planning?")
            {
                $.post("concorunt.php?val=1&id=<?php echo $id?>&"+$("#EventForm").serialize(), {
                }, function(response){
                    $('#ShowEvents').prepend($(response).fadeIn('slow'));
                    clearForm();
                });
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Enter event name.");
                $("#EventInput").focus();
            }
        }); 
</script>
```

But nothing is happening.

Comment: Close your CDATA and your document.ready function and you don't need CDATA

Comment: tried but nothing is happening

Answer (score 0):

You did not close your document`ready` function. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
// <![CDATA[   -->  Either remove this or close this.
.....
.....
}); //Missing those braces in your code
```